# Не работает программа после комментирования строки. Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

У меня почему-то не получается комментировать код в Питоне. Именно после того, как я набрал код в блокноте, если я ставлю # и пишу по-русски комментарий, после чего программа тупо не запускается, если уберу комментарий, то программа спокойно включается и работает, еще если после решётки напишу английские символы, то все хорошо! Что мне делать? Вот пример:

```
print ("hello world") #пишем привет мир
```

и программа не работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема из-за русских букв. С ASCII всё должно быть нормально. Решение -- определить кодировку исходного файла. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/
Отрывок, из pep:

Defining the Encoding
    Python will default to ASCII as standard encoding if no other
    encoding hints are given.

```
To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must
be placed into the source files either as first or second
line in the file, such as:

      # coding=<encoding name>

or (using formats recognized by popular editors)

      #!/usr/bin/python
      # -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-

or

      #!/usr/bin/python
      # vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name> :
```

Кроме того, если у Вас винды, то при сохранении в utf-8 некоторые программы могут добавлять сигнатуру (BOM-Byte Order Mark) -- '\xef\xbb\xbf', которую python учитывает и без комментариев кодировки (Ну а если cp1251 -- то magic comments, см. выше)

У меня всё нормально с магическими комментариями, но python 2.6, не 3.x

Comment: а можно пошаговую инструкцию что мне делать) а то я почему то ничего не понял ;)

Comment: @вова сысков AkelPad например:  
файл- сохранить как...  
кодировка- utf-8  
галочку BOM снять  
сохранить  
примерно так же во всех текстовых редакторах.

Comment: ухты спасибо!!! он терь ещё и начал русские буквы понимать!!!

Answer (score 3):

в начало файла добавить #coding: utf-8
например

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding: utf-8

print 'Hello!' # тестовый комментарий по-русски
```

Answer (score 1):

[PEP 0263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

> Python will default to ASCII as standard encoding if no other encoding hints are given.
>
> To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must be placed into the source files either as first or second line in the file, such as:
>
> ```
> # coding=<encoding name>
> ```
>
> or (using formats recognized by popular editors)
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> # -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> # vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name> :
> ```